# What's a word for a batch of batches?

Tags: single-word-requests

I have a program that does a job on batches of 100 items.  It's too slow on its own, so I'm going to write a program that runs multiple copies of that program, giving each one a batch of 500 batches, so 50000 items in each batch-of-batches.

I'd like a single word for the batches of batches.  I'm not looking for just any old synonym of "batch", but for a word which includes the sense of being batched at a higher level - though if such a word doesn't exist for "batch" and does exist for a synonym, I'd be happy with the pair.

Comment: Perhaps *ream* and *quire* ?  Or *ton* and *hundredweight* ?

Comment: meta-batch like language and meta-language.

Comment: Normally words like 'hyper' or 'super' or 'meta' would be used as prefixes in this context. 'Hyper-batch', 'Super-batch', 'Meta-batch'.

Answer (score 2):

Although the question doesn’t make it clear whether the poster wishes a name to use in his code (which would be off-topic, and depend on the names already taken for data structures in the programming language) or to use in user instructions or documentation, I will make a linguistic suggestion based on a precedent where there is a vowel change.

If Bytes are lots of Bits, then:

> A **Bitch** might be a suitable word for lots of *Batches*

(Or unsuitable, but that’s life, as they say.)

This would also have the advantage of allowing a further level of complexity by another vowel change:

> A **Butch** could be used for lots of *Bitches*

*Footnote*

“Lots of” may be regarded by non-informaticians as poor style, but in programming almost every word you can think of for a collection of objects (that too) already has a specific meaning. However this suggests an alternative approach, using the simple vernacular, rather than Latin or Greek, to form a prefix:

> **lota** might be a suitable general-purpose prefix, e.g. a **lota-batch**

And then:

> for a further level of complexity one could use **wota**, e.g. a **wota-lota-batch**

However an internet search suggests that in some parts of the world there might be cultural resistance to *lota*.

Comment: I would say "gaggle" -- a little less off-color.

Comment: @HotLicks — If you wish a gender-neutered alternative, I’ve a different one in mind, which I’ll add later. Also, a higher level variant of the current offering using another vowel change.

Comment: It's all Greek to me. Are you joking or serious?

Comment: @Lambie — you’re confusing lota with iota. It’s a serious joke. Choosing programming class names is important, because the name should indicate the function but not the implementation (list, array, stack etc). And as I mentioned, all the obvious names are already taken for data structures. So my second tranche of suggestions might be useful to anyone who is familiar with “watalotigot”. Unfortunately I prefer suffixes so the classes involving wibbles are grouped alphabetically and separated from the wobbles, eg wibble,  wibbleGroup, wibbleAssembly.

Comment: I am not confusing anything as I still do not understand your answer. You are not explaining it correctly to someone who has no idea of these naming protocols. You could do better.

Comment: @Lambie Sorry, let me try to explain better. Computer programs often store numbers etc at particular locations, but because we can change their values we call them variables and give them names. A variable storing information about a customer might be called “Client”.  We can expect a company to have many clients so we may want to create a variable of a different type to store clients. We need to give this a descriptive name, ClientSomething, but avoiding replacing Something by one of the structures (set, list etc) in which the data can be kept. We may even have several groups of clients…

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest *set*.

It's a universal word for any grouping of similar items.

> Each set contains 500 batches.

Or even *batch-set*.